# Is it a good practise to validate email addresses using SMTP validation?

Tags: smtp, email-validation

Let's imagine that I have a site with some features that require email validation (eg. user registration). Of course I will validate emails using regex but once upon a time I saw SMTP validation in someone else's code. What good and bad sides has SMTP validation?

I can assume the following pros and cons:

**Pros:**

- We can check out some email addresses for existence (not all SMTP servers allows this feature).

**Cons:**

- Our site can be [blocked](http://www.spamresource.com/2007/01/whatever-happened-to-vrfy.html).
- Maybe we can use this to make webserver going down. Webserver will take domain part of email address and make request to it. We can create fake SMTP server that will receive request but will make great delay to response. Maybe if we force webserver to make dozens of such checks it will not be able to answer other clients.
- Not all SMTP servers provide this capability.

Please be constructive.

Comment: Verify it by sending an email & requiring them to click a link/enter a code. That is the only way to do it.

Comment: @VBCPP: Did you read the question, actually? :)

Comment: @AmalMurali It's not very meaningful to discuss details of a suboptimal approach when the optimal approach is well-documented, trivial to implement, and obvious.

Comment: @VBCPP It goes without saying. But we can notify user that his email is invalid before he will understand that he has mistaken. Moreover there are other cases when user must enter his email and we can't send confirmation message.

Comment: Yes, you didn't state a reason for validating the address. I could enter president@whitehouse.gov, that's a valid address. You would still want to confirm that I actually own it.

Comment: What are some scenarios where an email address is required but you cannot use it?

Comment: @VBCPP Regex will check that email looks like correct address. SMTP validation will check that email exists. Message will check that you are the owner of this email address.

Comment: @tripleee Online shop that allows you to buy goods without registration and it needs your email to send you invoice.

Comment: Should you remove php tag, as question and accepted answer are not php specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim removed tag. Yep looks like a duplicate, can be marked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"SMTP Validation" I assume refers to the SMTP `VRFY` command, and in this day and age you would be a fool to trust in it. It's a great feature if you're a spammer because it allows you to enumerate email addresses for a given server.

No one in their right mind will expose this command to the internet and have it respond with anything other than `252 send some mail, i'll try my best`, aka "I'm only going to validate email addresses during an actual mail transaction".

The only *sane* use of `VRFY` these days is as an *internal* interface between a spam filtering appliance and the mail server hiding behind it.

**TL;DR** Don't use "SMTP Validation", it will be horribly unreliable *at best*.

If you want to validate that a user has entered a valid email address, then send it an email with an activation link/code.

Comment: I like your answer :). You have confirmed my assumptions.

Comment: What are the other ways for verifying email address without sending emails ?

Comment: @Elby: none, zero, null, empty set, nada. The *only* reliable method of validating email addresses is to send it an email, and have someone perform an action based on the information inside of that email. This can also cover you for Double Opt-In which helps you not be classified as a spammer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is a bit old but I came across this when I tried to implement something similar and just want to share my thoughts.

In my case I have a registration form where customers of a online platform enter their email address (which probably already costed money to bring them there because some come via paid ads). They have to double opt in anyway. So having a confirmed email in the end is not the problem.

But the customer picks a username, enters a bunch of data (including an email address with a typo). What is the result? Right, the user does not get the confirmation mail and can't continue. He might think that it will arrive later and does other stuff. Chances are that he completely forgets about the registration and is gone. Even if he does not, he has to fill the form again, pick a less appealing username or ask the adminstrator to change the email in the database.

In my case I already transfer the email address to the webserver when the user changes to another input field. This is done to check if there is an account with the same address already. So it was easy to add some additional checks on the server side.

First thing was a simple syntax check. Does not help that much, but was needed for security reasons anyway for further processing.

Then the address is splitted to a local and a domain part. While we cannot say  much about the local part without asking the server, we can still check whether the domain part was entered correctly. Only thing the script does, is checking if there are MX-Servers for the domain. If the list is empty, chance is high that there is a typo in the domain part.

If you want to go further, you can still use a VRFY or try to send a fake email you abort after RCPT TO. You still cannot say anything dependable if the server tells you that the mailbox exists or if it asks you to send a mail and see what happens. But I guess in the negative case you can be pretty sure that there is actually no mailbox with that name.
I would, however, use some cheap external cloud server to proxy those smtp checks to not hurt the reputation of the web server.

Another approach would be to track the activation mail AFTER the registration form was sent. It is quite a bit of work to get the response of the recipients mail server to the web application again and you even need some ajax to show it in the browser. But in that case you could ask the customer on the activation-mail-was-sent-page to  correct it if it was wrong.

In the end this some sort optimizing the conversion funnel and you absolutely have to evaluate if it is worth the effort.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Sammitch's answer, there are email validation services available via API that can provide SMTP validation - sometimes down to the mailbox level - for reasonable prices.

You can find these with a simple Google search, but I'm told LeadSpend and QAS (an Experian subsidiary) are among the best of the bunch.